# How to include header file generated by catkin srv?

Tags: catkin, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is:

```
/home/ira/code/ros_groovy/src/sam_semantic_map_builder_dir/src/sam_semantic_map_builder_src.cpp:2:55: fatal error: sam_semantic_map_builder_dir/srv_add_file.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I run:

```
catkin_create_pkg sam_semantic_map_builder_dir pcl pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs
roscd sam_semantic_map_builder_dir
mkdir -p srv
```

vim srv/srv_add_file.srv

```
string msg_object_name
---
float32 msg_x
float32 msg_y
float32 msg_z
float32 msg_roll
float32 msg_pitch
float32 msg_yaw
```

vim src/sam_semantic_map_builder_src.cpp

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sam_semantic_map_builder_dir/srv_add_file.h>
...
```

vim CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sam_semantic_map_builder_dir)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   srv_add_file.srv
 )
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sam_semantic_map_builder_dir
  CATKIN_DEPENDS pcl pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs
  #  DEPENDS system_lib
)
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(sam_semantic_map_builder_bin src/sam_semantic_map_builder_src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sam_semantic_map_builder_bin ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

vim package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>sam_semantic_map_builder_dir</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The sam_semantic_map_builder_dir package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag --> 
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="ira@todo.todo">ira</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

What am I missing?

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185660/how-to-include-header-file-generated-by-catkin-srv?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing 2 things:

1)
In addition to `add_service_files` you need to call `generate_messages` (Typically just decomment this in the default generated CMakeLists.txt):

```
## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs  # and/or other packages containing depended messages
)
```

If you added this your code will compile 'most of the times'. However, the srv headers need to be compiled before your exec target and the order of command evaluation is not yet fixed. In order to fix the order you add:

2)

```
add_dependencies( sam_semantic_map_builder_bin ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp )
```

after `add_executable`. This makes your exec depending on the <>generate_messages_cpp thereby only allowing the exec target to be compiled after the msg headers are generated............

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick search leads to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/?answer=54418#post-id-54418) answer by WilliamWoodall in [How to specify dependencies with "foo_msgs" catkin packages](http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/).

See also [C++ message or service dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/cpp_msg_dependencies.html) on the excellent [How to do common tasks](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html) page (you're most likely using package format 1).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1